# How can I display/visualize this type of data in a chart?

Tags: graph, charts, data-visualization

I have data which is related to movement of players in a game.  Each player reports back the distance, speed, current coords and a TimeStamp.

This game may have 1/2k players playing at any given moment in time, so plotting this on a may would just be blurry... I was wondering what useful (if any) data can be extracted and visualized from this data?  I attempted to create a line graph of average speed and running total of movement (two different graphs), but these don't seem to be what the user wants.  The user isn't sure what they want, but they "know" that a line graph is the wrong way to go!

Any information you could give me on what data might be useful to extract or how best this data could be visualized would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe instead of just blurriness you could show the current intensity of activity per region, cell, pixel, whatever. An activity intensity map? To see where the action is?

Comment: @Benjamin I see you are now stalking me.  I like the idea of an activity intensity map, but it's not going to be too useful in this scenario.  Although it is VERY useful for something else I'm doing! It's so useful that if you worked for me I'd give you a bonus! :)

But for this movement stuff, it's kinda meh :P

Comment: Well this is a weird question then! Another idea would be to display stats on a limited number of players. But how can anyone guess the answer to this question if there is no goal? All I can think of is to list and organize all the possible perspectives on that data and then get some actual guidance from the user. "How best this data could be visualized" totally depends on the purpose of visualizing it in the first place. Why does the user want to see this data?

Comment: They don't know!  That's the issue, in reality they want metrics and, well anything which can be used for further analysis.  OK, so if my question were worded "Which ways can I display this type of data to extract value?" how would you answer it?  An intensity map is nice, but what other ways might you approach this?

Comment: There are a TON of options I think. I am not a data-visualization expert but it sounds basically like the players could be shown separately, all at once, totaled, averaged, etc. And then their actual stats (distance, velocity, duration, time, location) can be shown individually or in relation/proportion to each other (totaled, averaged, you know). That would probably produce a large number of possible perspectives right there? And then you would have options for how to visually present these perspectives. Plain text, icons/colors, graphs/contours 1D, 2D, 3D. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Another question that comes up is do they primarily want live data or historical data?

Comment: It's all historical data.  Also, yes, all of those are valid options.  But I'm wondering what do you think the best way to represent it would be?  If you were looking at people's movements playing paintball for example, what would help you analyze what happened best?  BTW, my movement can last up to 10 days, over 100km, so a map is probably not that useful...

Comment: If there are teams, that would be a significant factor. Personally, I would totally want a map - sorry. I don't really see how the graphs would be helpful unless in combination with a map. You don't think a map could work if it had a slider control for the time (instant replay, frame-stepping)? Partial movement trails? Zooming? Sounds cool to me. Maybe I will be a paintball combat analyst now. Movement is X and Y. Visualizing historical X and Y basically begs for an interactive map doesn't it?

Comment: This may give some ideas: http://www.gallup.com/poll/151103/GOP-Presidential-Nomination-Race-2011.aspx

Comment: ha, I wish I was in the U.S.A for stuff like that.  We find out about our politicians when they are involved in some sort of scandal!  We already have all of the above.  This is only for analytics, so realistically they might want to see bursts of speed in order to drill down into TICs (activity), but I was hoping to give them more.  At the moment they don't like the line, but they have the "cool" features you already suggested.  So I need something that looks nerdy but is easy to comprehend at a glance... Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer, we don't seem to be going anywhere worth going!

Comment: Ha, you didn't even answer.  Throw together a few suggestions of how you would try to show paintballers stuff about their movement (what would be useful for them to see so that they could learn from it?), on an indiviual/group basis.  I'll accept what you put together just for the sheer genius of the activity intensity graph! :)

Comment: That's ok I don't need the points. Basically what I was saying was either make one EXCITING interactive display with EVERY feature, or just dump the data into BORING tables and bar graphs or whatever and link it all together so it can be tediously navigated and look very nerdy. Or do a COMBO of both like the link I showed. I don't really have any idea of what would be useful for paintball combat. This does not seem like something that has a real answer unless I was like the ultimate master of data visualization.

Comment: Perhaps you are and you just don't know it yet... If you think of anything  else useful (like the intensity map thing) then make sure you let me know!!!

Comment: ok, thanks for the challenging discussion. I enjoyed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a TON of options I think. I am not a data-visualization expert but it sounds basically like the players could be shown separately, all at once, totaled, averaged, etc. And then their actual stats (distance, velocity, duration, time, location) can be shown individually or in relation/proportion to each other (totaled, averaged, you know). That would probably produce a large number of possible perspectives right there? And then you would have options for how to visually present these perspectives. Plain text, icons/colors, graphs/contours 1D, 2D, 3D. Do you see what I mean?